# How to merge duplicate products with same warehouse and get the average price

Tags: javascript

merge duplicate product with same warehouse and get the total quantity and create new price by making average price ((total quantity / 100) * total price)

```
let inventories = [
  { product: 'laptop', price: 50, warehouse: 'Kismayu', quantity: 6 },
  { product: 'phone', price: 20, warehouse: 'Mogadishu', quantity: 3 },
  { product: 'notebook', price: 30, warehouse: 'Mogadishu', quantity: 2 },
  { product: 'phone', price: 40, warehouse: 'Mogadishu', quantity: 1 },
  { product: 'phone', price: 60, warehouse: 'Hargeisa', quantity: 3 },
]
```

Final output:

```
 [
    { product: 'laptop', price: 50, warehouse: 'Kismayu', quantity: 6 },
    { product: 'phone', price: 24, warehouse: 'Mogadishu', quantity: 4 },
    { product: 'notebook', price: 30, warehouse: 'Mogadishu', quantity: 2 },
    { product: 'phone', price: 60, warehouse: 'Hargeisa', quantity: 3 },
  ]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: How can the price of `phone` and `Mogadishu` be 24 after merging 20 and 40?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused about the average price for 'Mogadishu' and 'phone'. Your expected average price is 24, whereas the average of 20 and 40 is 30. Assuming 30 is the correct calculation, here is a functional programming solution:

```js
const inventories = [
  { product: 'laptop', price: 50, warehouse: 'Kismayu', quantity: 6 },
  { product: 'phone', price: 20, warehouse: 'Mogadishu', quantity: 3 },
  { product: 'notebook', price: 30, warehouse: 'Mogadishu', quantity: 2 },
  { product: 'phone', price: 40, warehouse: 'Mogadishu', quantity: 1 },
  { product: 'phone', price: 60, warehouse: 'Hargeisa', quantity: 3 },
]

let result = Object.entries(inventories.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if(!acc[obj.warehouse]) acc[obj.warehouse] = {};
  if(!acc[obj.warehouse][obj.product]) acc[obj.warehouse][obj.product] = [];
  acc[obj.warehouse][obj.product].push([obj.price, obj.quantity])
  return acc;
}, {})).map(wp => [wp[0], Object.entries(wp[1]).map(pp => ({
  warehouse: wp[0],
  product: pp[0],
  price: pp[1].reduce((a, pq) => a + pq[0], 0) / pp[1].length,
  quantity: pp[1].reduce((a, pq) => a + pq[1], 0)
}))]).flat().flat().filter(val => typeof val === 'object');
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "warehouse": "Kismayu",
    "product": "laptop",
    "price": 50,
    "quantity": 6
  },
  {
    "warehouse": "Mogadishu",
    "product": "phone",
    "price": 30,
    "quantity": 4
  },
  {
    "warehouse": "Mogadishu",
    "product": "notebook",
    "price": 30,
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "warehouse": "Hargeisa",
    "product": "phone",
    "price": 60,
    "quantity": 3
  }
]
```